# Oracle Cross Join with various parameters

Tags: sql, join, oracle11g

```
SELECT tb.ID, tb.NAME, square
FROM MY_TABLE tb
         CROSS JOIN
         (SELECT POWER(tb.ID,2) as square FROM DUAL)
```

I want to figure out whether it is possible to do something like this, cross join particular result set to subquery while putting in value from result set to subquery.

Power function here is just for the example. Instead of it I have massive subquery that should be completed with various parameters.

This particular example fails with ORA-00904

Basically I need to add to each row of the given result set the result of subquery, but I need to complete this subquery using data from this row, so each time subquery would be completed with various data.

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help.  To me it doesn't seem like you want a corss join.  as Dual has 1 record and one can't coorlate that way.  Unsure of your expected esults and sample data leaves the question vague.

Comment: You need a `LATERAL` _derived table_. Something like  `...FROM tb CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT ... FROM t2 WHERE t2.x = tb.y) ...`.

Comment: There's no LATERAL in Oracle 11g, @jarlh.

Comment: @Littlefoot, oops. Didn't know that.

Comment: You can do this directly in the `select` clause.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
(SELECT POWER(tb.ID,2) as square FROM DUAL)
              -----
              this
```

because that subquery doesn't "see" `my_table` (whose alias is `tb`).

---

Code that *works* might be e.g.

```
select tb.id, tb.name, x.square
from my_Table tb
cross join (select power(tb2.id, 2) as square from my_table tb2) x;
```

but ... you didn't say what you actually expect as result.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle 11, you could derive the column without a join:

```sql
SELECT tb.ID,
       tb.NAME,
       POWER(tb.ID,2) AS square
FROM   MY_TABLE tb
```

From Oracle 12, if you want to use a sub-query then you can use a `LATERAL` join:

```sql
SELECT tb.ID,
       tb.NAME,
       square
FROM   MY_TABLE tb
       CROSS JOIN LATERAL (
         SELECT POWER(tb.ID,2) as square FROM DUAL
       )
```

or `APPLY`:

```sql
SELECT tb.ID,
       tb.NAME,
       square
FROM   MY_TABLE tb
       CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT POWER(tb.ID,2) as square FROM DUAL
       )
```

Comment: I used POWER function just as an example. In reality it should be a pretty big subquery.

Comment: @РоманЕвлампиев At the moment, everything that you want to do can be done by adding derived columns to the `SELECT` clause and do not need to use a sub-query - even if you need to add lots of columns to the `SELECT` clause. If you have an example where it is impossible to solve without using a lateral joined sub-query then you should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77988279/edit) to include this detail.